# E: Unable to locate package nvidia-driver-340

Tags: nvidia

what does this code :
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-driver-340

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the Personal Package Archive (ppa) was not added or maybe there is a typo.

Please run the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

Ref: [Install Latest NVidia 340.46 via ppa](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/install-latest-nvidia-340-46-via-ppa/)